# How to avoid two frameworks conflicting due to redeclared function?

Tags: php

**The Problem**

I'm working on a site which utilises two PHP frameworks running in parallel, Wordpress and CakePHP. Both of them contain a core function called `__()`.

I know I can modify the core files of either framework to check if the function is declared and then not declare it:

```
if (!function_exists('__')) {
    function __() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

However, the problem is that both frameworks need to be automatically updated from time to time, and when this happens, the core files get rewritten and the function comes back, causing fatal errors.

Wordpress is out of our control. Editors using the CMS want to be able to update the framework and plugins automatically from the Wordpress admin panel. This means I cannot really modify the Wordpress core to solve the problem, as they will just overwrite my changes every time they update.

CakePHP is updated by the developers, via Composer. Of course one basic solution would be to ensure that all developers know that when performing a Composer update, the core file declaring the function needs to be modified to fix the fatal error. This is still a pretty bad solution.

---

**The Question**

So although I am 99% sure there is no permanent solution to this, I'm wondering if any PHP gurus can think of a really clever, albeit slightly unconventional/messy, way of solving this with some code in the custom application within CakePHP. If there is something that can be done which I don't know about in PHP.

**How the Application Works**

- The basic marketing pages of the site are pure Wordpress. CakePHP does not load on those pages.
- On some sections of the site which require more complex functionality, CakePHP is loaded *first*. Before the page is rendered, CakePHP loads the Wordpress framework, then renders the page through Wordpress. *These are the pages where both frameworks collide on the same function being declared twice.*

**My Thinking**

1. When CakePHP is bootstrapped on a page, let it run up until the view is due to be rendered. At this point, only CakePHP has declared the function.
2. Check if the function exists before Wordpress gets loaded.
3. Somehow prevent Wordpress from redeclaring the function, ahead of time. We write this in our application code, which is fully controlled by the developers and committed to our Git repo.

I feel ridiculous posting this question, as I'm sure this is impossible, but if there is a really clever way of solving this, it would be so useful.

Comment: Fork CakePHP, apply your changes, and update it regularly from downstream.

Comment: How about something like this - apply a patch after install or update to cakephp: https://github.com/netresearch/composer-patches-plugin . Ideally cakephp or WordPress would be completely namespaced and not declare global functions...

Comment: @jedifans *"Ideally cakephp or WordPress would be completely namespaced and not declare global functions"* Tell me about it...

Comment: This sounds like a good case for inheritance. I've not done it, so I can't tell you exactly how, but I know that you can extend composer packages, and autoload them.  So using that logic you should be able to extend Cake's composer package and override the methods you need to.  Then your composer update won't over write your modifications.

Comment: unrelated: watch out for CakePHP starting/interfering with settings for the session. I don't know if it is, but this is a common problem loading apps in the same request.

Comment: @SteveClay I already wrote some code to bridge the frameworks which solved any session problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ceejayoz said, fork CakePHP, and maintain your project on that fork.

Make a commit that will serve your project and that you can submit to the Cake team. As you suggest, make `__` declaration conditional on it not already existing, declare it `@deprecated` in its phpdoc, and make a namespaced version that you'll convert everything to. Send that as a PR to Cake.

When you need to update your fork, merge the upstream branch into yours. **You much watch the incoming Cake changes for use of the `__` function** and change them accordingly. Git will not catch these.